# Safely iterating over Unicode strings while respecting grapheme clusters

Tags: unicode

Is there a canonically "correct" method for iterating over arbitrary unicode strings by grapheme? Eg: For splitting or reversing strings?

My naieve solution is leveraging a regex that is simply `\P{M}\p{M}*`, aka "anything that isn't a Mark, followed by zero or more Marks", but I'm wondering if there might be edge cases where the blanket `\P{M}` breaks down?

I've done my best to search for previous solutions, but frankly they're lost in a sea of bad solutions that are roughly "1 code point == 1 grapheme".

Comment: There are several at ``github``. One of them is this [grapheme-splitter](https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter)

Comment: Defined at [Grapheme Cluster Boundaries](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries)?

Comment: @Darkman ~1500 lines of hard-coded cases are not particularly helpful to me.

Comment: @Sammitch There are no shortcuts to implement grapheme clusters. For example like this: ```1F1EF - (1F1EA, 1F1F2, 1F1F4, 1F1F5)```. As you can see there are gaps between code point `0x1F1EA` and `0x1F1F2`. And this is just one example and there are a lot more like them. So to get the correct graphemes, you'll need to filter a lot of specific code points.

Comment: @Darkman sure, but I'm not interested in someone else's pre-computed list. Among what I want to know is what the rules to generate that list were and what _that_ code looks like.